# Android Activity Flow

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two Activities, say A1 and A2. sequence being A1->A2
From A1 I start A2 without calling finish() in A1.
After I press the back button in A2 I want to trigger a function in A1.
However, if I use onResume() in A1, the function is triggered even during the start of activity A1, which I want to avoid.
It should only be called during the 'back' press of A2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well start A2 with `startActivityForResult` then in

A1 implement

```
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {

   // your code here

}
```

in A2 override onBackPresset to set result before finishing the activity. Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the other approach(one is as per Dimitar).

```
public class A extends Activity {
    public static boolean isCalledFromB = false;

    public void onCreate(Bundle instance) {
        isCalledFromB = false;
    }

    public void onResume()
    {
        if(isCalledFromB)
            dosomething();

    }

    public void dosomething() {

    }

}

public class B extends Activity {
..............

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            A.isCalledFromB=true;
            finish();
        } 
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Then override **`onBackPressed()`** method inside the A2 Activity.

FYI: It works in Android 2.x otherwise you can use onKeyDown() in Android 1.x

### 2nd Way:

Start A2 activity inside the Activity A1 by using **`startActivityForResult()`**. So when you press back key, it will redirect you to **`onActivityResult()`** inside the A1 activity. So inside the onActivityResult(), you can write that code.

Comment: but the funtion to trigger is in A1

Comment: overriding onBackPressed() and setting a flag is a valid possibility, however startActivityForResult is way better since one can also add data to the Intent.

Answer (score -1):

`onResume` will always be invoked no matter if its the 1st time or its a restart. You can achieve the same by overriding `onRestart()`

Edit 1:

Use startActivityForResult instead as suggested by other users.